# Downloading orai18n-mapping.jar from Oracle Maven

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, ojdbc

I am following this [guide](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-oracle-maven-repository-without-ides) to download `ojdbc8.jar` in my gradle build. But after deployment, I am having a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/i18n/util/LocaleMapper` which seems to be from `orai18n-mapping.jar`.

Does anyone know if this jar is available in Oracle Maven? The alternative is to download the Oracle Server and get it from the `jlib` folder but we want to avoid this as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I looked at many sites and there is no Maven dependency for that.

My solution was to download JDev 11.2 (you can download the Java Edition, it is a 112MB zip file, not need to install).

Jar location: ../modules/oracle.nlsrtl_11.1.0/orai18n-mapping.jar

JDev:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/downloads/jdev11124download-1970562.html

I uploaded jar to Google Drive for you.

Here is orai18n-mapping.jar:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1g3C-rEh0iTM6wxtivKueeVAumm04gmV1

Comment: Thanks for another alternative solution. But having to use both maven and other tricks to pick up missing dependencies here and there does not sound right to me at all. To add to this, I also needed to disable jar scanning in tomcat since it is searching for `gdk_custom.jar` which is present in `orai18n-mapping.jar` manifest file. I am hoping someone from Oracle finds this and tells us if we are following a non-recommended approach since I don't see other people raising this issue.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks you are using the maven.oracle.com repository. This installs a bunch of unnecessary stuff include the following. The xmlparserv2 will need to be exclude from being downloaded.

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>xmlparserv2</artifactId>    
      <version>12.1.0.2</version>     
  </dependency>
```

If you downloaded the "ojdbc8" from the website it does not include this file, its not even listed and therefore should not be needed.